# How to shift an element to the left side of the list item circle

Tags: html, css

I want to shift the `timeline` part to the left of the list-item 'circle'.

How can I accomplish this?

```
<div class="blah">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <div class="timeline">
        saturday, october 21st 2018
      </div>
      <p>
      this is some text here
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="timeline">
        saturday, october 20st 2018
      </div>
      <p>
      this is some text here hello world
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wkhv90gz/1/

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the intended result ?

Comment: Haven't you tried negative values for left margin [?](http://jsfiddle.net/wkhv90gz/3/)

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I did but the text just disappeard partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float` to pull it to the left, then set a `margin-right` to get the spacing how you want it.

```
.timeline {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkhv90gz/2/

Comment: confused why this worked, don't you have to go outside the normal flow?

Comment: The `float` tells the browser that other content should float around the styled section (left or right). You can see some more details here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp